# Task failing silently (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using AppEngine's deferred.defer, roughly based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062045/568962).

It works fine in my development environment, but in my deployed version the tasks starts, then fails silently, then retries. I can see the task in the tasks view, and the only hint of an error is in the task's Previous Run tab it says:

> Last http response code   404

[image]

But I dont know what that 404 refers to.

I have logging.info statements in the function being passed to deferred, but nothing is being written to the log. I've wrapped the whole thing in a try/except block, to logging.error any errors, but still nothing shows in the logs.

It looks like there is something preventing the task from ever starting, but I dont know what. I've added the built-in to my app.yaml:

```
application: xxx
version: xxx
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- deferred: on

handlers:
...
```

How do I debug this?

Thanks

Comment: not sure whether it matters, but only this version has the 'deferred' builtin, and it's not the default version.

Comment: Show us the log entries from the logging console for the task.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I added an image of the Task Queues view. This is the only place I'm seeing an error (the 404). Nothing relating to this task is being written to the logs.

Comment: Check the logging page, and set it to 'all requests'. Also check alternate versions. If it's not logged there, it's not being run.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the tasks was trying to run on my default version, even though it was being called from a different version (thanks for the hint to check that Nick).

It's an easy fix. When first calling deferred I do

```
version = os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'].split('.')[0]
deferred.defer(<fn_name>, <fn_variable>, _target=version)
```

Thanks

tom