# GAE: Logs from tasks does not appears in dashboard

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working with the Google App Engine Tasks Queue feature (Push).

In local, with the dev server, everything is working fine but once deployed my task fails.
I have put logs in it (logging python module) but they do not appear in my dashboard logs.

Is there anything to do to make it works?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here: [Task failing silently (GAE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569104/task-failing-silently-gae)

I have to specify the target application unlike what is specify in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#target
(task enqueue in the current application version).

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running on the appspot.com domain or your own custom domain? In the former case it should work without you specifiying the target. In the case of a custom domain we are aware of problems with this scenario. Please file a bug in either case.